# Solution of checking retention of users through RESAMPLE

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

For the purpose of finding frequency and retention of users on a service, I tried to re sample data but fail as it lose parts of my data.

*Please note that the frequency could be month, year, every 3 days or 5 days*

This is sample data:

```
a=pd.DataFrame([[Timestamp('2019-01-01'),'Jack'],
                [Timestamp('2019-01-15'),'Jack'],
                [Timestamp('2019-02-6'),'Lina'],
                [Timestamp('2019-03-23'),'Tom'],
                [Timestamp('2019-03-22'),'Jack'],
                [Timestamp('2019-02-14'),'Jack']],columns=['Date','Name'])
    Date  Name
0 2019-01-01  Jack
1 2019-01-15  Jack
2 2019-02-06  Lina
3 2019-03-23   Tom
4 2019-03-22  Jack
5 2019-02-14  Jack
```

My expected result:

```
            Name
Date            
2019-01-31  Jack
2019-02-28  Jack
2019-03-31  Jack
2019-02-28  Lina
2019-03-31   Tom
```

My so far attemption:

```
a=a.set_index('Date')
a.index=pd.to_datetime(z.index)
a=a.resample('M').pad()
```

The result

```
            Name
Date            
2019-01-31  Jack                #Most of data dropped
2019-02-28  Jack
2019-03-31   Tom
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
a=pd.DataFrame([['2019-01-01','Jack'],
                ['2019-01-15','Jack'],
                ['2019-02-6','Lina'],
                ['2019-03-23','Tom'],
                ['2019-03-22','Jack'],
                ['2019-02-14','Jack']],columns=['Date','Name'])

a['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(a['Date'])
a = (a.set_index('Date')
     .groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M')).agg(list)
     .explode('Name')
     .reset_index()
     .drop_duplicates()
     .sort_values(['Name', 'Date'])
     .reset_index(drop=True))
```

Output:

```
        Date  Name
0 2019-01-31  Jack
1 2019-02-28  Jack
2 2019-03-31  Jack
3 2019-02-28  Lina
4 2019-03-31   Tom
```